# Android: Zoom not effecting preview frame data passed to onPreviewFrame()

Tags: android, android-camera, nexus-4, lg

I'm building a camera app which access the preview frame by implementing

```
android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback#onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera).
```

When I change my camera zoom by calling the

```
android.hardware.Camera.Parameters#setZoom(int zoom)
```

it doesn't seem to have any effect on the data i get in the onPreviewFrame. The preview display itself is effected as expected.

This is happening on LG Nexus 4.

How can I get the actual zoom which is applied on the preview data. do I have any way of knowing if my device actually applies zoom on the data or not?

Thanks,

Comment: were you able find a solution for this?

Comment: Same issue with the Moto X 1st Generation. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

not exactly a solution but... you can set the scene to HDR (`Camera.Parameters.setSceneMode("hdr")`) and that makes the data to behave as expected (but, of course, then HDR is on). 
what I did was to work around it and actually crop the data only on the Nexus 4. I used the `getZoom()` method to detect zoom and then cropped accordingly.